# На сколько сложнее Ruby (Rails) против (Си, Java, C#) ?

Tags: python, java, c#, ruby

Ребятя, скажу сразу, я работаю на чистом Си и пишу дровишки под различные устройства, вопрос в том что я очень алчный человек, страшно жадный и скурпулезный по этому зарплаты в 500у.е мне не хватает (возможно из-за моей жадности), особой перспективы для Си-шников у нас нет, платить больше никто не хочет, друг с другого города (он сам Питонист) часто мне советоват спрыгнуть в WEB и притом на Ruby (хотя он сам пишет на Питоне), я всвою очередь пытался познать Java, но сильно "красивым" и простым мне показался этот самый Руби, товарищь уверяет что Руби очень простой и интересный и платят больше чем посредственному "Си-шнику", тоесть мне ... Буду рад если поговорите со мной на эту тему !

Comment: C рельсами сложилась ситуация такого характера, что в мире они являются одним из стандартных инстурментов для среднекрупных проектов, а их использование в проектах меньшего масштаба (по крайней мере в России) не так велико. В результате зарплаты действительно могут быть очень неплохими, но спрос пока не очень велик (про то, насколько этот спрос удовлетворяется ничего не скажу, потому что не знаю).

Comment: Вы пишете драйвера на Си? Такие люди на вес золота. Оставайтесь в своей специализации, и не идите туда, куда может пойти любой студент. Могу примерно оценить ваш труд на $4k+. Нужно немножко поискать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Изучать надо не языки, а парадигмы. Основные парадигмы:

1. Процедурная, Вы ее уже знаете. Зарабатывать на хлеб можно, даже зная только ее.
2. ООП. После С лучше всего, пожалуй, Objective-C. На нем чаще всего пишут игрушки для всяких Айфонов и Айпадов. Вот Вам и икорка на хлеб.
3. Конкатенативная. Посмотрите на язык Factor (на ютубе есть видео автора языка).
4. Функциональная. Начать советую с сайта hexlet.org (курс "Структура и интерпретация компьютерных программ").
5. Есть еще одна парадигма, которую я советую изучить, потому что она применяется очень часто и не зависит от языка - это автоматное программирование. Погуглите поучительную историю про игрушку Starship Troopers.

А вообще практика показывает, что важен не инструмент, а степень владения им. Я сам доходил до этого слишком долго, к сожалению. Если бы сейчас вернуть все назад, я бы тупо программировал на C (на котором, кстати, и пишу сейчас), вместо того, чтобы изучать новомодные языки и технологии. Да, они тоже нужны, но это не значит, что они нужны именно Вам и именно сейчас. Когда понадобится - освоите за месяц (при условии, что уже знакомы с соответствующей парадигмой). Причем никто не запрещает использовать эти знания в старом языке. На том же C можно много чего реализовать. Вот мне, например, понравилась одна очень удобная структура данных в другом языке программирования. И я написал для себя аналог на C. Конечно, он является лишь жалким подобием и микроскопическим подмножеством той структуры данных, но именно это подмножество и именно с такими функциями мне и нужны.

Почитайте еще про Вадима Башурова AKA papabubadiop. Человек пишет код без всяких затей и архитектурных заморочек. Но пишет! Написал уже сотню игрушек. Заработал миллион баксов.

Answer (score 3):

Если интересуют вопрос того, кому и сколько платят, то гораздо проще и логичнее зайти на любой сайт по поиску работы (hh, superjob, etc) и вбить там соответствующий запрос, который сможет прояснить многое - и размеры зарплат, и требуемый опыт, и необходимые навыки, и всё это будет с градацией по регионам и достаточно объективно, без личных пристрастий типа "учи   <%languege_name%> потому что мне он нравится".

Что касается Ruby,  то я бы не стал утверждать, что программистам на нем платят куда как больше, чем программистам на Си, да и то, что проще - не факт (хотя бы потому что Си сам по себе довольно прост) Про интересность, впрочем, судить не берусь.

Если вы живете и работаете не в крупном городе, то скорее всего это будет сменой шила на мыло - наиболее вероятно, что мало платят там не только сишникам, а вообще всем. К тому же вакансий для программистов на Ruby и в Москве не то что бы уж навалом, не говоря про прочие регионы.

З.Ы.

> я очень алчный человек, страшно жадный и скурпулезный по этому зарплаты в 500у.е мне не хватает

такой зарплаты даже грузчику маловато будет, какая уж тут жадность. Кстати, слово "скрупулёзный" к жадности отношения не имеет.

Comment: @DreamChild Спасибо за ответ ! Просто сам Си действительно прост, по этому Java мне кажется такой громоздкой и большой, а Руби вроде меньше и интересней !

Comment: @Vladimir_X если вы ищете что попроще, то вас это погубит. Это для каких-нибудь оболтусов вроде манагеров по продажам "что попроще" будет хорошим вариантом, а программист обязан всю жизнь учиться и развиваться, не избегая в том числе и сложноных вещей чтобы не стоять на месте